# How enable Taxonomy to work with Basic Pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When I create an Article I choose an appropriate Tag from my Taxonomy List and save the article. When I click the tag after I save the article I get a list of articles with the same tag.

But how do you make a Basic Page work this way? I've researched Manage Fields and Manage Displays in admin-structure-types-manage and I CAN choose a tag and save it with the Basic Page...but I can't click on a tag on a Basic Page and get a list of all Basic Pages with the same tag.

Can you assist?

Comment: There might be other things to check for, so let me know if my answer does'nt do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**You probably have your field being displayed as *Plain text***. To display as links:

1. Go to your content type and ***Manage Displays***
2. Find the *Tags* field and make sure the ***Format*** column has the ***Link*** value

Note that I'm assuming that you added the *Tags* field to your *Basic Page* content type and it's showing up in your page.

Comment: Yep, just what I was about to write.  The other thing I'd mention to the OP is that he might be getting confused once he does get a list of content tagged with the term he clicked.  It will be a list of *all content* in the site tagged with that term (regardless of content type), so it will be a mix of Basic Pages and Articles.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've got the Tags field:  field_tags, enabled in Manage Fields  and in Manage Display the Tags are in Region: Content, Label: Inline; and Format: Link with the # sign. The tags do appear when I create a Basic Page. But still no joy...I can't seem to get any "Basic Page" to appear when I click a Tag link. I can access a Basic Page by creating a Menu Item...but not a Tag.

Comment: Could you double check your Tag field type? Go to Manage Fields and make sure it is Term reference.

Comment: Now I'm confused, I thought that you could NOT click on them? Can you actually click on them?

Comment: Yes, my Tag Field Type is Term Reference. And yes, I can input a Basic Page and save it. The tag appears at the bottom of the Basic Page. I have input two Basic Pages, both with the same Taxonomy string from my Taxonomy List. But when I click the Tag at the bottom of either of the Basic Pages, I go to a page with the Taxonomy Term at the top, but no content below.

Comment: Sorry, so yes, I CAN click on a Tag and go to a page...with no content.

Comment: It's strange, as this is a Drupal core behaviour. It's hard to tell, but other things to check: 
1) Try enabling the bartik theme (in case it's a theme issue) 
2) Double check your nodes are marked as "Published" 
3) Are you using Views? (if so, there's a View that overrides the default Drupal taxonomy results page) 
4) In Manage Display, go to Teaser and check that you have visible fields.